# Laravel 5.2 No connector for []

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have just installed Laravel 5.2 and i'm trying to get the reset password feature to work, but i'm getting the following error:

> InvalidArgumentException in QueueManager.php line 150:
>
> No connector for []

Does anyone know how to fix this?

My `.env` file contains:

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=xxx

DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=mydb
DB_USERNAME=mydb
DB_PASSWORD=xxx

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=iron

MAIL_DRIVER=mailgun
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailgun.org
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=postmaster@mydomain.co.uk
MAIL_PASSWORD=xxx
MAILGUN_DOMAIN=mydomain.co.uk
MAILGUN_SECRET=key-xxx
```

Comment: Please post your .env file

Comment: @KaloyanDoichinov I have edited my original post and included the contents of the `.env` file.

Comment: Do you have the iron-mq client library installed? The queue is configured for IronMQ but it's complaining about that driver

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Laravel 5.2 removed the IronMQ queue driver. It is no longer included by default.

If you would like to use IronMQ, you will need to use the [Laravel Collective IronMQ package](http://github.com/LaravelCollective/iron-queue).

Once you install this package (installation instructions provided by package), your issue should be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `config/queue.php` file to make sure the `driver` property is set to `env('QUEUE_DRIVER')`.

Also make sure that the iron-mq dependency is met (documented in the [Laravel 5.2 Queue Configuration](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queues#configuration))

Comment: and run `php artisan config:cache` just in case, this was the cause of the problem in my case, default config was cached